# Change ApplicationUser properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to change my properties for application user but getting error
at

```
IdentityResult result = await Usermanager.UpdateAsync(model);
```

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The goal is to change the `Fullname`,`Website`,`Email` for `ApplicationUser` if he desires to. Is there a simpler way of doing this instead of what I am trying to do here? or Am I on the right track?

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditUserData(string FullName, string Website, string Email)
{
    ApplicationUser model = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
    model.Email = Email; 
    model.UserName = Email; 
    model.FullName = FullName; 
    model.Website = Website;
    IdentityResult result = await Usermanager.UpdateAsync(model);

    return RedirectToAction("Settings","Admin");
}
```

trying some things out

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> EditUserData(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);

        ApplicationUser model = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        model.Email = user.Email;
        model.UserName = user.UserName;
        model.FullName = user.FullName;
        model.Website = user.Website;
        IdentityResult result = await UserManager.UpdateAsync(model);
        //UserManager.Update(model);
        //db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Settings", "Admin");

    }
```

page just refreshes. and no changes have been made

Comment: You're now starting to go in the right direction. You need to debug and see what is in `IdentityResult result`. Can you do that and update your question with the contents of `result`?

Answer (score 0):

I think, the action parameters isn't passed. You should merge the parameters as a complex objects if you want to apply post. So, why don't you use `ApplicationUser` as parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> EditUserData(ApplicationUser user)
{

        ApplicationUser model = db.Users.Find(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        model.Email = user.Email; 
        model.UserName = user.UserName; 
        model.FullName = user.FullName; 
        model.Website = user.Website;
        IdentityResult result = await Usermanager.UpdateAsync(model);

        return RedirectToAction("Settings","Admin");
}
```

Comment: still getting the same problem, but is it becasue im not passing all things such as. model.AccessFailedCount,   model.EmailConfirmed, etc.

Comment: Did you debug "model" ?

Comment: not quite sure what to debug, im not so experience with it

Comment: It is quite difficult to inspect problem without debug.